# R polygons within boundaries

Tags: r, leaflet, rgeo

I am trying to get all polygons that are within leaflet map boundaries. No need to bother about leaflet, the question is more about rgeos or other methods (or primarily about correct function). I tried variety of methods and they work OK if shapes intersect boundaries, but cannot get a shape that is within the boundaries (not touching it)

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

subzones<- readShapeSpatial("subzones.shp")


N<- 51.5139 
S<-51.5130 
W<-(-0.1899)
E<-(-0.1890)

BB = matrix(c(W,E,E,W,W,N,N,S,S,N), nrow=5,ncol=2)
BB = Polygon(BB)
BB = Polygons(list(BB),1)
BB = SpatialPolygons(list(BB))
```

The example is not of course possible to reproduce but in general the BB is very small far smaller than any of subzones - it is only for the test purposes. If I make larger BB than of course it will catch some subzones, a small one certainly is contained within one of them. Translating it to any reproducible example - when I zoom in into London, I cannot get 'England' as it does not intersect anything. I tried without success rgdal(gIntersection, gIntersects, gCovers, gCrosses, gOverlaps, gWithin, overGeoGeo, gContains and probably few other ones) and raster (crop). My aim is to get a subset of subzones (spatial dataframe or dataframe) that are visible within a map box. Any idea what I am doing wrong? or simply how to do it?

To make it possible to reproduce:
the shapefile here http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip

```
library(maptools)
getinfo.shape("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp") 
world.map <- readShapeSpatial("TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.shp")
```

the BB above is a little rectangle somewhere in London - how to find a world.map records that might be within the bb - either crossing it or fully contained (here it would be UK only, but i would like it to work even if the BB is size of Europe)

EDIT: It was a problem with the shapefile containing multilines rather than proper polygons, thank you

Comment: If I make `plot(world.map[which(gIntersects(world.map,BB,byid=TRUE)),])` I get a map of UK.

Comment: it works on the example, but failed to work on my initial project;( it probably means that my shapes are not correct polygons (maybe). Any idea how to check it out? They look OK on carto.com. Actually I checked them and they are multilinestrings, while the worldmap are proper polygons - I assumed incorrectly they were polygons, and this is why the methods failed